# What is the best approach in Python to convert data files with 'Not Applicable', 'Not Available' and save those values as null in postgreSQL

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I am a new python coder, I am working on an ETL process to read csv files to pandas dataframe, then insert into postgreSQL.

The raw file has ~30 data values shall be saved as null in database, otherwise the database  will throw data type errors.

I am trying to find the best practice suggestions to achieve this. Shall the replace/convert happen at raw file level, pandas data frame, or any suggestions?
Is there a simply and easy way to replace a group of string to something else, other than loops.

```
    '',
    'N/A',
    'N/R',
    'NI',
    'Not Applicable', 
    'No Commitment', 
    'No Commitment ', 
    'Not Collected', 
    'Not Collected ', 
    ' Not Collected ', 
    'Not Meaningful', 
    'Not Disclosed', 
    'NotApplicable', 
    'NotCollected', 
    'NotDisclosed', 
    'NotMeaningful', 
    'No Information', 
    'NoInformation', 
    'NULL', 
    '-', 
    '#N/A', 
    '#NotApplicable', 
    'No Fossil Fuel Reserves', 
    'No Data', 
    '#VALUE!', 
    'NotAvailable', 
    'Not Available'
```

Comment: Are the above values to be found in all fields or some subset?

Comment: good question @AdrianKlaver. other than some key fields, expect to see them in all other fields

Comment: it depends on the scope of your project, but if it's not big data or whatever, it doesn't matter where you do it. You could for example keep a list of these not available strings and replace them with None just before you insert into the database.

Comment: this is what I did, it works fine but I am not sure if it is efficient performance wise.
        data_file = pd.read_csv(file_path, error_bad_lines=False, dtype=DTYPES)

        for x in null_values:
            data_file = data_file.replace(x, np.nan)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion all.
Initially I thought there might be a way to avoid looping. It turned out the looping is not that bad. This is what I did to solve it.

```
null_values = (
"",
"N/A",
"N/R",
"NI",
"Not Applicable",
"No Commitment",
"No Commitment ",
"Not Collected",
"Not Collected ",
" Not Collected ",
"Not Meaningful",
"Not Disclosed",
"NotApplicable",
"NotCollected",
"NotDisclosed",
"NotMeaningful",
"No Information",
"NoInformation",
"NULL",
"-",
"#N/A",
"#NotApplicable",
"No Fossil Fuel Reserves",
"No Data",
"#VALUE!",
"NotAvailable",
"Not Available",)

data_file = pd.read_csv(file_path, error_bad_lines=False, dtype=DTYPES)

for x in null_values:
    data_file = data_file.replace(x, np.nan)
```